# qsort comparator function doesn't order the entire array (leaves 1 element out)

Tags: c, gcc, comparator, qsort

Relevant code (index is the size of the array):

```
typedef struct elemento {
    unsigned long linha;
    unsigned long coluna;
    double valor;
} elemento; 

elemento Representados[MAXN];
qsort(Representados, index, sizeof(Representados[0]), lcomparator);

int lcomparator(const void *el1, const void *el2) {
    int l1 = ((elemento *)el1)->linha;
    int l2 = ((elemento *)el2)->linha;
    int c1 = ((elemento *)el1)->coluna;
    int c2 = ((elemento *)el2)->coluna;

    if (l1 < l2) {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (l1 == l2) {
        if (c1 < c2) {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (c1 == c2) {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (c2 > c1) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }

}
```

gcc also prints out the 'control reaches end' warning for lcomparator, but I don't see how it would be possible for my function to not return anything.

Comment: The innermost `if` does not have the "default" `else` case, hence the warning.

Comment: Unrelated, does it not bother you *at all*, those compiler warnings you *should* be getting, screaming that conversion from `unsigned long` to `int` potentially loses precision?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I've removed the innermost if's else, but qsort still doesn't sort correctly.

Comment: Please show how `qsort` is called with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: the compiler didn't warn me about those (-Wall -ansi) but I've fixed it and qsort still doesn't sort correctly.

Comment: Maybe I missed something, but all you're trying to do is order dominant on l1,l2, and if equal, on c1,c2, right? [Why not just do this?](https://pastebin.com/gmvNrPzk). Note, it could be even shorter with more ternary operations, but it's probably clearer as-is.

Comment: You'll get the idea of why people recommends you to post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example from this post.  You act as if you were defending your case in court.  You talk about the probes, but you don't show them at all. You say that `index` is assigned the correct value.  I don't know at this moment if you have assigned, initialised or `#define`d it, and how, but you're right... continue as so, and you'll get desperate, because you tell all us the absolute truth about your code... and don't tell nothing about the mistake.  You don't see it. And so we don't.

Answer (score 6):

```
else if (c2 > c1) {
    return 1;
}
```

is wrong and should be

```
else if (c1 > c2) {
    return 1;
}
```

or better

```
else {
    return 1;
}
```

and of course replace `int` by `unsigned long`

Comment: Good catch on the comparison.

Comment: Take a look at automated way to identify the issue in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion:

1. Change the types of the function local variables to `unsigned long`. You are losing precision when they are of type `int`. That might be the source of the problem you are seeing but it's hard telling without actual values.
2. The core logic can be made simpler by using a helper function.

Here's an updated version of your function.

```
int compare_helper(unsigned long l1, unsigned long l2)
{
   if ( l1 < l2 )
   {
      return -1;
   }
   if ( l2 < l1 )
   {
      return 1;
   }
   return 0;

   // The line below does the same thing but relies on the logical expressions 
   // to be 1 or 0.
   // return (l2<l1) - (l1<l2);
}

int lcomparator(const void *el1, const void *el2) {
    unsigned long l1 = ((elemento *)el1)->linha;
    unsigned long l2 = ((elemento *)el2)->linha;
    unsigned long c1 = ((elemento *)el1)->coluna;
    unsigned long c2 = ((elemento *)el2)->coluna;

    if ( l1 != l2 )
    {
       return compare_helper(l1, l2);
    }

    return compare_helper(c1, c2);
}
```

Comment: A `helper` function seems OTT. Function `lcomparator` should be as efficient as possible. Perhaps `inline` it?

Comment: @WeatherVane, Won't that be an attempt at premature optimization? One could use the `(l2<l1) - (l1<l2)` idea if that turned out to be performance bottleneck.

Comment: I am sorry, but your first attempt to answer - challenged by 2 valid (and now deleted) comments has not got much better. This is a poor answer from such a high-rep. Downvote. The answer I upvoted actually spotted the bug.

Comment: @WeatherVane, I respect your opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Previous comments and answers have already shown the type difference between `unsigned long` and `int`, and the comparison bug. Your code may *in practice* always return a value but the compiler does not like the hanging `else`.

I suggest the following:

```
int lcomparator(const void *el1, const void *el2) {
    unsigned long l1 = ((elemento *)el1)->linha;
    unsigned long l2 = ((elemento *)el2)->linha;
    unsigned long c1 = ((elemento *)el1)->coluna;
    unsigned long c2 = ((elemento *)el2)->coluna;

    if(l1 < l2) {
        return -1;
    } 
    if(l1 > l2) { 
        return 1;
    } 
    if(c1 < c2) { 
        return -1;
    } 
    if(c1 > c2) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to an already correct answer by @Stargateur, here's an automated way to find bug in your code using [SortChecker](https://github.com/yugr/sortcheck):

```
LD_PRELOAD=$HOME/SortCheck/bin/libsortcheck.so ./a.out
a.out[3024]: qsort: comparison function is not symmetric (comparison function 0x400526 (/home/yugr/src/so/a.out+0x400526), called from 0x4005c6 (/home/yugr/src/so/a.out+0x4005c6), cmdline is "./a.out")
```

This warning says that `lcomparator` returns inconsistent results when order of arguments is swapped. To further debug this issue, run with

```
export SORTCHECK_OPTIONS=raise=1
```

and examine generated codedump.